# Como usar um layout do Figma no Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, svg

Tenho um projeto no Figma com algumas telas, por exemplo a da imagem abaixo:

[image: Tela do Figma]

O Figma gera o código XML ou SVG de cada componente, como o da "tela":

```
<!-- layout/*.xml -->
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/editar_perf"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clipToOutline="true"
    android:background="#FAFAFA"
 />
```

E por exemplo o do botão laranja com um lápis:

```
<!-- layout/*.xml -->
<View
android:id="@+id/ellipse"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
android:background="@drawable/ellipse"
 />


<!-- drawable/ellipse.xml -->
<vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="48dp"
android:height="48dp"
android:viewportWidth="48"
android:viewportHeight="48"
 >

<group>

<clip-path
android:pathData="M 48 24C 48 37.2548 37.2548 48 24 48C 10.7452 48 0 37.2548 0 24C 0 10.7452 10.7452 0 24 0C 37.2548 0 48 10.7452 48 24Z"
/>

<path
android:pathData="M 0 0L 0 48L 48 48L 48 0"
android:fillColor="#FFBA31"
/>

</group>

</vector>
```

Eu preciso colocar cada um desses trechos em cada arquivo? Como no `layout.xml` e `drawable/ellipse.xml`? Há alguma forma de inserir a tela com todos os componentes direto em um xml?

(Quando gero o SVG da tela toda, o arquivo é gigante, e dá erro se tento usar o  Vector Asset Studio para inserir).

Comment: Leila vc não pode gerar um SVG da tela inteira, vc tem que gerar pequenos SVG por exemplo, uma para o "botão laranja com um lápis" outro para o "switch button", outro para o icone ✔ e por ai vai.